# Ng-model and ng-max same value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have `ng-repeat` table with the input field (number), with dynamically data get from API.

Problem is `ng-model` and `ng-max`

here is code

`<input type="number" ng-model="item.impressions" ng-max="item.impressions" class="form-control inputPolje" name="item.impressions"/>`

output in view:
`Number: 5000`

And `ng-max` with the same value as ng-model, also 5000.

When someone tries to input a number greater than this in `ng-max` I show an error message.

Because, my `ng-model` and `ng-max` have the same value, in this case, 5000, when I enter in input field any other number, example 111111111, `ng-model` have new value but `ng-max` also get this same value 111111111 and don't throw an error.

How to solve this?
Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you need the initial value of item.impressions for your ng-max you can try the following

```
<div ng-init = "item.maxValue = item.impressions">
    <input type="number" ng-model="item.impressions" ng-max="item.maxValue" class="form-control inputPolje" name="item.impressions"/>
</div>
```

[**Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/OlbsEHATYZrpU3KLmayz?p=preview)